# What is the meaning of "como" in the 'Como te (alejar) de la orilla, no te traigo mañana'?

Tags: gramática, tiempos-verbales, conjunciones

Given this sentence:

> **Como** te (alejar) _____ de la orilla, no te traigo mañana.

This sentence is from an exercise and I guess the correct form of the verb "alejar" is "alejas".

On the other hand, the sentence sounds like an "oración condicional" and I suppose the meaning of "como" here is "if". (If you get away from the beach, I will not bring you (with me) tomorrow.) Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. "Como no te comas la carne, no tendrás postre" "If you don't eat your meat, you don't have any dessert"

Comment: (from @roetnig) so it is indeed subjunctive: _Como te **alejes** de la orilla, bla_. It is a warning to someone (sounds like a parent to their child).

Comment: @fedorqui - The sentence would also work without the subjunctive.  It really depends on how far along OP is in their particular textbook.  Also, the meaning depends on the conversational context, to some extent, doesn't it?  Let's say the child was already given the rule, but wasn't able to follow it.  Then mightné the parent follow up by saying: "Dado que te alejaste de la orilla, no te traigo mañana"?

Comment: Volkan, for documentation, see Definition 5 the first clump of definitions of "como" at http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/como. // Could you situate the exercise for us within the structure of your textbook?

Comment: @aparente001 , ""Dado que te alejaste de la orilla, no te traigo mañana" 
this won't work as the second part is on present, as is the conditioning part, for this to work, the second part has to be in future. 
"dado que/como te alejaste de la orilla, no te traeré mañana"  also the sense of the phrase changed completely from if.. to as/because

Comment: @Mike - Future can be expressed in two ways: "No te traeré mañana" or "No te traigo mañana."  In fact, the pattern for the subjunctive version, with "como" meaning "if," also requires the concept of future in the second clause (which can be expressed either as "traigo" or "traeré").

Comment: Thank you very much. Aparente001, yes, one of the meanings in the dictionary here is "if." My own dictionary app do not include it. The context is as you have guessed. It's a story about childhood when his father was warning him not to leave the beach as he didn't know how to swim. As for the subjunctive, the excercise specifically asks for the indicative more of the verb. So, I suppose the sentence's meaning is not hypothetical; his father would definitely forbid him to go to the beach if he left the shore. For probability or hypothetical meaning, we can use subj. (ie. alejes), can't we?

Comment: @aparente001 to me "no te traigo mañana" sounds conditional, and in your example the condition was already met, so "no te traigo mañana" sounds out of place. it should be already stated "no te traeré mañana"

Comment: @Mike - See https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26843/9385 (but we might need to wait a day or two to get a helpful answer).

Comment: @VolkanErsoy - I'm afraid I don't understand "more of the verb."  Also, "here" in "One of the meanings in the dictionary **here**." // I don't understand yet how far along in the book this exercise appears.  What chapter is it in, and could you show us the table of contents?  Also, could you give us the exercise in context, along with any hints that might have been provided?

Comment: Aparente001, I take private courses and the materials are selected from different books. I take private courses and the materials are from different books. This is from a Cuban book: Aprendemos Español 3.

Comment: Here is the complete exercise:.  Completa con la forma verbal correcta del infinitivo entre paréntesis:
a. Cuando yo era niño me gustaba mucho ir a bañarme a la playa y si mis padres me (llevar) ___________, 
iba todos los días. Mi papá no me dejaba alejarme de la orilla y siempre decía: “Como te (alejar) _____
______ de la orilla, no te traigo mañana”. Si entonces (saber, yo) ___________ nadar como sé ahora, mi 
papá no me habría dicho eso. Mi padre era muy estricto, y si nos (alejar) ___________ un poco, no nos 
dejaba ir al día siguiente.

Comment: @Volkan consider editing your questions with all these important details. Just click in [edit]!

Answer (score 3):

Besides other uses (for comparisons), *como* is employed to mark conditions and causes. The meaning depends on context and above all on the tense and mood of the verbs.

In your example the answer would be

> *Como te alejes de la orilla, no te traigo mañana.*

As you already deduced, this is a conditional; but in this case, with *como*, you need to use the subjunctive mood and say *alejes*, instead of the indicative *alejas* (which you would use if the conditional phrase began with *si*). This kind of sentence is rather common with threats:

> *Como te vea otra vez por aquí, llamaré a la policía.*

You use the subjunctive (*[tú te] alejes*, *[yo te] vea*) because the situation is hypothetical.

You will also find *como* introducing a cause. In this case the verb will be in the indicative. You can have a perfectly parallel phrase to the one above:

> *Como te alejas de la orilla, no te traigo mañana.*

This means: "Since you're getting away from the shore, I won't bring you tomorrow." It's grammatically correct, but the actual situation doesn't look plausible, so I guess the answer should be the other one.