# Using the present indicative to communicate about the future

Tags: gramática, tiempos-verbales, adverbios, futuro, presente-indicativo

In Spanish and some other languages (e.g. French and German), we can use the present indicative tense plus an appropriate adverb to communicate about the future, for example

> Mañana voy al supermercado.
>
> Je vais au marché demain.
>
> Morgen gehe ich einkaufen.

This way of communicating about things to come is more informal than the future tense proper (*Iré / J'irai / Ich werde gehen*).

How can I document this to a native Spanish speaker who isn't aware of this feature of Spanish?

Also, how would I explain this to a Spanish learner?

*Motivation for the question: [a comment](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26811/what-is-the-meaning-of-como-in-the-como-te-alejar-de-la-orilla-no-te-traig?noredirect=1#comment44793_26811)*

*Note, I tried to find a note about this in the DRAE but all I came up with was http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/modelos-de-conjugacion-verbal which didn't help.*

---

Now that Gustavson showed me what this is called, I was able to find some more documentation.  For Spanish speakers: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usos_desplazados_de_los_tiempos_verbales

For Spanish learners: https://www.espanolavanzado.com/gramatica-avanzada/489-presente-prospectivo

Comment: ohh, now i see what you are talking about now, 

yeah i have heard this way of speech in the south america and in Spain, but in Mexico you have to say it in the future tense 
"mañana voy a ir al super mercado" 
probably is said like that to make the sentence shorter

Answer (score 3):

In [this publication](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=8FZcwTIYcPcC&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=%22presente%20prospectivo%20o%20presente%20con%20valor%20de%20futuro%22&source=bl&ots=AHH4lXgxAJ&sig=9iN7Dtb8nsRjGVnLhw4GE1MRsy0&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidg6P6xY7cAhUCPZAKHZDVAJYQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22presente%20prospectivo%20o%20presente%20con%20valor%20de%20futuro%22&f=false) you can find some good examples of the present tense being used to express future time in Spanish:

> El **presente prospectivo** o **presente con valor de futuro** alude a hechos posteriores al momento de la enunciación....  Este uso del presente es característico, aunque no exclusivo, de los compromisos, de la descripción de planes, actuaciones previstas o programadas, etc.
>
> *(The **prospective present** or **present with future value** refers to actions that will take place after being spoken about....  This use of the present tense is commonly seen for appointments, descriptions of plans, anticipated or programmed performances, etc.)*

A future time reference may be required for the sentence in the present to be interpreted as future:

- El tren **sale a las 8**.

As can be seen above, most of these sentences will refer to scheduled actions or events.

Sometimes, the present has future value in contexts in which a threat is implied:

- Sigues comportándote así y te **echo** de la clase.

In conditional clauses (unlike adverbial clauses of time in which present subjunctive is used), present indicative is used to refer to a future situation:

- Si **gana** Bélgica el Mundial, hago una fiesta. Pero si **gana** Inglaterra, me mato. (It's a joke...)

Notice that in the sentence above both the condition and the result refer to the future and are expressed in the present tense.

Answer (score 0):

For a Spanish learner who's fluent in English, I think it could be explained like this:

It's similar to using the present continuous in English to talk about something that will happen in the future, for example:

> Tomorrow I'm starting a new job.

"Present continuous" is also sometimes called "present progressive" or "I-N-G form."

The precise equivalent of the *future tense in Spanish* would be

> Tomorrow I will start a new job.

And with a contraction, this would be

> Tomorrow I'll start a new job.

Note, although it's not as common, sometimes the present indicative is used for this also, e.g.

> Tomorrow I start my new job.